# Buscar número de llamada entrante en una Base de Datos

Tags: android, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una app que al recibir una llamada, captura el numero de la llamada entrante y lo busca en una BD en el teléfono. Hasta ahora las consultas a la BD las hago bien, con esta clase:

```
public class MiBaseDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Ruta por defecto de las bases de datos en el sistema Android
    private static String DB_PATH = "/FelixDroyd/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "etecsa.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    //contructor con referencia a la memoria interna del movil
    public MiBaseDatos(Context context) {
        super(context, "/storage/external_SD" +DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;

    }
    /**
     * Comprueba si la base de datos existe para evitar copiar siempre el fichero cada vez que se abra la aplicación.
     *
     * @return true si existe, false si no existe
     */
   public boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {

            String myPath = "/storage/external_SD" +DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
//si llegamos aqui es porque la base de datos no existe todavía.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Persona recuperarPERSONA(String numero) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String[] valores_recuperar = {"number","name","address","identification","province"};
        Cursor c = db.query("movil", valores_recuperar, "number=" +"'"+ numero+"'",
                null, null, null, null, null);
        Persona cuerpo = null;
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

           cuerpo = new Persona(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2), c.getString(3), c.getInt(4));
            db.close();
            c.close();
        }else{
          cuerpo = new Persona(" "," ", " ", " ", 1);
        }


        return cuerpo;
    }    

}
```

Ahora, el numero de la llamada entrante lo capturo con la siguente clase:

```
public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String incomingNumber;  

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //verfica que esta entrando una llamada y gruada el número...
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            MiBaseDatos MDB = new MiBaseDatos(context);
            Toast.makeText(context, "LLama de: " + MDB.recuperarPERSONA(incomingNumber) + " " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        } 

    }   

}
```

Lo que pasa ahora es que cuando hago una referencia a la clase MiBaseDatos y llamo al método MDB.recuperarPERSONA(incomingNumber) pasandole el numero de la llamada entrante el método no busca correctamente, aunque le quite la variable "incomingNumber" y le pase un numero fijo no funciona, pero parece que es solo en la clase MyCallReceiver porque en el MainActivity tengo echo un buscador aparte que si funciona, que al escribir un numero te hace la consulta correctamente.

Lo que devuelve la consulta es "nombre-del-paquete-de-la-aplicacion.Ojeto Persona@numeros", algo como com.felix.droid.Persona@4443565....

Comment: puedes compartir el constructor persona... si es como se acostumbra deberías poner: MDB.recuperarPERSONA(incomingNumber).getNombre (o como obtengas en name en tu constructor)

Comment: hahaahahhaah, que imbecil soy, es eso mismo, y mira que le di cabeza, y en el mainactiviy lo debuelbo bien, pero bueno esas cosas pasan...y a q estamos aki, me gustaria que cuando entre la llamada en ves de mostrar un Toast, que saliera un cartel o algo que dure hasta que se atienda la llamada o se culgue....

Comment: añadiré el comentario como respuesta y en cuento a tu otra consulta, debes usar un alertDialog

Comment: el Toast se muestra correcatmente pero cuando lo remplazo por el  AlertDialog este  no sale, alguna idea de porque?  @Maguz

Comment: revisa el contexto, lo habia anotado mal..., por favor responde sobre la respuesta y no acá, que los comentarios se borran

Answer (score 0):

debes poner: MDB.recuperarPERSONA(incomingNumber).getNombre (o como obtengas el name en tu constructor)

en cuanto a cambiar el Toast, prueba con esto:

```
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Titulo llamada")
                .setMessage("LLama de: " + MDB.recuperarPERSONA(incomingNumber).getNombre + " " + incomingNumber")
                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Que hacer si acepta
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Que hacer si cancela
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .show();
```

Comment: si ya yo habia arregladoe eso, le pase el contexto como muestra la respeusta pero no sale...@Maguz

Comment: ya yo habia rerglado eso, le pase el contexto como se muestra en la respuesta pero igula no sale @Maguz

Comment: lo unico que se me ocurre es el contexto, prueba con tu variable context, getApplicationContext() o YourActivityClassName.this

Comment: el problema es q esa clase no esta asociada a ninguna actividad